# Hiding the left navigation is making the question page grid too small

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design, left-navigation

I don't like changes so I decided to hide the new shiny left navigation and to keep the good old design with 2 columns instead of 3.

After hiding the left navigation I noticed that the main Q&A page stretches differently than the question page.

**This is a screenshot of the Q&A page:**

[image: Main Q&A page]

As you can see, the question list wrapper element has a `.flush-left` class with `margin-left: -24px;` that stretches the list to start from the left of the hamburger menu.

**And this is a screenshot of a random question:**

[image]

As you can see from the second screenshot, the body of the question has a different offset from the hamburger menu. It has the following style: `width: calc(100% - 300px - 24px);`  (Note the: **- 24px**).

I believe that this is a bug because it's very noticeable and looks weird IMO. I tried changing the `#mainbar` element style to `width: calc(100% - 300px); margin-left: -24px;` and it seems to make things to look a bit better.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it was tested on Windows 10, using Google Chrome version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: 14 replies... +106 unchecked rep... my OCD is driving me crazy!

Comment: Well, at least my circles and arrows are a freehand drawing