# Can we hide the new line on the left of the page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, left-navigation

Today a new line was added to the page on the left hand side of the screen.

[image]

For users that hide the left hand nav could we get rid of the line? It makes the page feel more cramped when not using the left hand nav.

Comment: Counter argument:  since the hidden left pane's background is a different color than the main question body's background, add a line to the right and restore balance.

Comment: I was so confused when I saw this- It made me think if I accidentally click that space (which, both that and to the right look slightly darker than the content area to me, so that isn't helping) that it would close a pop-up that the content is on. >.> Which, I think, is mainly because I just saw news articles on Yahoo that did that, but still. It threw me for a loop.

Comment: The fact that the line does not line up with the line next to the burger menu is disturbing me greatly.

Comment: Yes, the unorganized crawling nature of the lines is somewhat disturbing, not to mention the horizontal line that sticks out on, for example, the top questions page.
┴┬

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm annoyed as well...

Comment: Ugh, they moved it from the sidebar menu. What the heck, SO designers.

Comment: If you resize your browser window to exactly 1216px order is restored... Phew.

Comment: Wait, how do you have a menu icon on the left?

Comment: @BSMP Hide the side nav. Profile > Settings > Navigation > Hide left navigation

Comment: @Turnip Oh, that's just where the menu goes when it's hidden. Thanks.

Comment: @Turnip that's only on meta, on main so the left area is white... so it's just a dangling line on the left

Comment: @j08691 It's even worse when you consider they also run a UI/UX design site.

Comment: Well they just host UX; whether they make use of its knowledge is another matter :P

Comment: I never understood why the line was only added on one side to begin with. Seemed odd. If there's gonna be a border, be consistent and give all the other sites the bodybg too.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SE: [Why was a vertical line added on the left for users who collapse the left navigation? Can it please be removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313930/289905).

Comment: It might also be related to this bug:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369450/hiding-the-left-navigation-is-making-the-question-page-grid-too-small

Comment: This is driving me crazy, that little line break to the side is so annoying, it's not even centered in the Stack Overflow logo, everything is off center. Who does the UI testing at Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Makoto would prefer it that way, it lets the middle panel "stick out" from the background and would be more appealing

Comment: It seems to be gone now. I used to see it, but now I can't.

Comment: The line! She's a gone!

Comment: no! it came back. what a shame!

Comment: @NinaScholz Looks like they are aware: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314844/can-the-vertical-line-please-be-removed-again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed for sites that don't normally box in the content area: [Why was a vertical line added on the left for users who collapse the left navigation? Can it please be removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313930/why-was-a-vertical-line-added-on-the-left-for-users-who-collapse-the-left-naviga/314138#314138)

Answer (score 23):

For some reason they moved the right border of the sidebar (which was hidden when you hid the sidebar) over to the `#content` element as a border-left, instead.

So here is the now requisite "You can revert this with a user style" solution:

```
#left-sidebar { border-right: 1px solid #d6d9dc; }

#content { border-left: none; }
```

Or just use the `#content` style if you don't want a border at all.

Comment: How would I apply this?

Comment: I use robogist, but any extension that lets you set arbitrary styles would work.

Comment: @NathanOliver Stylus is one example of an addon that supports userstyles. You would create a new style, add these CSS rules into it, and then apply them to specific URLs or domains as appropriate.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks.  I wound up using Stylebot.