# Why has the new design on Stack Overflow made me breathe in?

Tags: discussion

I've just noticed a new design on Stack Overflow, and it makes it feel really restrictive. What's the thought process behind it? Why box things in?

For a start, it makes things look out of line. IMHO it's just not needed and actually makes it look like it was added for the sake of it.

Is it actually new or being rolled out?

[image]

As you scroll down it gets worse. There's a border on one side and not the other...it feels wrong.

[image]

Comment: I think it's part of an implementation of [my feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness/310940#310940) :( but they forgot the background color and the other 3 borders. Though... if they added teh background color, they could just remove that border.

Comment: I have a full left side nav, but yours is collapsed into a hamburger menu?  Is your screen touchscreen or something?

Comment: @ryanyuyu nope, desktop

Comment: @ryanyuyu There is an option to collapse the sidebar if you don't like it.

Comment: Related, this might even be a duplicate:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372304/4916627

Comment: I have a userscript called [VisualCrumbs](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/369480-visualcrumbs-stack-visuals) that works with the new responsive design and sidebar, it makes the page look like [this](https://image.ibb.co/kxdyVp/2018_08_09_15_13_52_Why_has_the_new_design_on_SO_made_me_breathe_in_Meta_Stack_Overflow.png). (Note: This is not for everybody, but I like it.) (Also, ignore the Image Wizard thing, that's a totally different userscript)