# The line... is back!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, left-navigation

[image]

A couple of weeks ago [a line appeared to the left hand side of sites across the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372304/can-we-hide-the-new-line-on-the-left-of-the-page).

The line [was removed for certain sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372548/746736) but has just reappeared on Stack Overflow.

After a quick scan of some other sites, it appears the line is back across the whole network.

Comment: The userstyle referenced here still works: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372308/

Comment: It's definitely not "across the network". I've seen it on Meta SE, SuperUser SE and a few other sites, but not on Software Engineering SE, Cross Validated, Japanese Language SE or on any beta sites.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe it only occurs on sites that have received the new design (i.e. [codegolf.se], [apple.se], [su], [sf]).